# Why is s=6n in AES Key Wrap?

Tags: aes, modes-of-operation, key-wrap

In AES Key Wrap, we apply 6n AES encryptions for an input of n 64-bit blocks. Informally speaking, we wrap the key 6 times. What is the motivation behind 6? Why not 4 or 10? Is there something like a treshold or trade-off coming from security vs efficiency concerns?

Answer (score 6):

The AES Key Wrap scheme (AESKW) was developed in the [ANSI X9.102](https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/ascx9/ansix91022020) standard by the X9F1 working group, though the scheme was first proposed by NIST and appears in [SP800-38F](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38F.pdf). Although, the ANSI group specified goals for key wrap algorithms (indistinguishability of ciphertexts under an adaptive chosen-ciphertext attack (IND-CCA2), and unforgeability of ciphertexts under an adaptive chosen-ciphertext attack) they gave no indication of why their choices of designs/parameters might achieve these. This opacity attracted some criticism from academic cryptographers (see e.g appendix A of [Deterministic Authenticated-Encryption
A Provable-Security Treatment of the Key-Wrap Problem](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/221.pdf) by Rogaway and Shrimpton).

The appendix note that the number of AES calls is large in comparison to other keywrapping schemes

> The number of blockcipher calls seems large: roughly 12 per block of data (the same price paid for $X$ or $H$). This is six times more than that used for AKW1.

among other criticisms. They do however note

> The above criticism notwithstanding, we find it likely that the mechanism is correct.[...] The modified Feistel network used here probably does have security (as a strong PRP) better than $\sigma^2/2\eta$, but it would be hard to prove.

In a (arguably) more tongue-in-cheek complaint in appendix F (and also The Journal of Craptology vol 3, November 2006) "Key Rap" they imply that the NSA may have had input into the design:

> Now NIST and X9
> and their friends at the fort
> suggest that you stick it
> in a six-layer torte

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer